# Class zipMoney\Api\CheckoutsApi does not exist

Tags: magento2, upgrade

After Upgrading Magento 2.4 and executing the command php bin/magento setup:di:compile, its generating error

[ReflectionException]
Class zipMoney\Api\CheckoutsApi does not exist

while I have already latest zip money version 1.0.1.

Comment: Hi there , can you please share us the error screenshot when you run that SDC command and share the class name where this path exists , this screenshots helps us more to debug this issue clearly.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply @BharathKumarJ issue resolved now its issue libreary class